# Meu GetDirectories() só trás um diretório, quando existe 5

Tags: c#

Tenho essa linha.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
```

Aí então eu tento pegar todos os subfolders, assim:

```
DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
```

O Array `dirs` só é carregado com um subfolder e não com os 5. Abaixo meu código completo:

```
private void CopyRenameFolder(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
        {
            // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                    "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                    + sourceDirName);
            }

            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
            //string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDirName, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }

            // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
                file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
            }

            // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
            if (copySubDirs)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                    CopyRenameFolder(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: A questão aí não é arquivos e sim pastas, por isso outro post. Não está me interessando arquivos nesse post e sim pastas, mas já resolvi e vou postar a resolução.

Comment: BigOwn, antes de fazer qualquer coisa, você deveria ler o post e ver o que ele busca e não saí fazendo as coisas pelo que você não entendeu.